# Django Haystack - Search on non-indexed many to many field

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-haystack

Is there a way of having only a filtered part of a model as a SeachQuerySet?

Something like:

query = SearchQuerySet().models(Entry.filter(categories__name='something'))

instead of

query = SearchQuerySet().models(Entry)

The field I want to filter by is a manytomany field and non indexed.

Answer (score 14):

The search index doesn't store any relations, it is therefore 'flat'. You can only add your categories' IDs to the index for `Entry` (note that you have to use a `prepare_`-method for this):

```
class EntryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    # your other fields
    categories = MultiValueField()

    def prepare_categories(self, obj):
        return [category.pk for category in obj.categories.all()]
```

The you can do something like:

```
category = Category.objects.get(name='something')
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Entry).filter(categories=category.pk)
```